# Base 10 Error with passing an int

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-3.4

The error i keep getting is when i try to determine weather the player has enough guesses left to keep playing. i am unable to figure it out does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue please i am stuck.
Also i am a beginner in python and i know there are other easier ways to do this i just do not know how.

here i my error i recieve:

```
 File c:  line 68, in initalize_loop
        total_guesses = int(total_guesses_left.get())
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[]'
```

here is my full code below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import random
import os
import sys
#Section the Functions are stored.

def loadWordList(words):
    try:
        fin = open(words)       
        for line in fin:
            tmp = fin.readline()
            wordList.append(tmp.rstrip("\n"))   
        fin.close
    except OSError as err:
        print("File Error: ", err, "\n")
        exit(1)

def exity():
    sys.exit()


def getHint(word, guessed_letter):
#Stores the word in characters in which the player cannot see but still gives the ammount of charaters.
    hint = ""
    c = 0
    while ( c <= (len(word) - 1)):
        if word[c] in guessed_letter:
#increments each hint that is correctly guessed unlocking the guessed letter.
            hint += word[c]
            c += 1
        else:
            hint += "_"
            c +=1
    return hint

def countOccurences(word, guess):
    c = 0
    count = 0
    while c <= (len(word)-1):
#Shows the ammount of times the letter occured in that word.
        if guess == word[c]:
            count +=1
            c += 1
        else:
            c += 1
    return count

def get_letter(*args):
    guess = inputted_value.get()
    guess = guess.lower()
    return guess


def valid_guess(guess):
    if guess.isalpha() and 1 == len(guess):
        return True
    else:
        user_help.set(invalid_guess)
    return False

def final_guess(*args):
    finalguess = inputted_value.get()
    finalguess = finalguess.lower()

def initalize_loop(*args):
    total_guesses = int(total_guesses_left.get())
    if ((int(total_guesses > 0)) and (secret_word.get() != word)):
        guess = get_letter()
        valid = valid_guess(guess)
        if valid == True:
            if guess in guessed_letter:
                invalid_input.set("You have already guessed that letter '{}'".format(guess))
            elif guess in word:
                invalid_input.set("That is a good guess! '{}' occurs {} time(s) in the secret word.".format(guess, countOccurences(guess, word)))
            else:
                 invalid_input.set("'{}' does not occur in the secret word.".format(guess))
            guessed_letter.append(guess)
            total_guesses =-1
        word_entry.delete(0, 'end')
        secret_word_value.set(getHint(word, guesses))
        total_guesses_left.set(total_guesses)
        print(guessed_letter)
    else:
        if(secret_word_value.get() == word):
            messagebox.showinfo(title= "Winner!", message=("Congradulations! You Correctly guessed the secret word: {}".format(word)))
            root.destroy()
        else:
            finalguess = final_guess()
            if finalguess == word:
                messagebox.showinfo(frame, title="Congratulations", message= ("Congradulations! You Correctly guessed the secret word: {}".format(word)))
                root.destroy()
            else:
                messagebox.showinfo(title= "Incorrect", message=("Sorry, the secret word was: {} ".format(word)))
                root.destroy()







root = Tk()
root.title('COSC 110 Guessing Game' )
frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding = '4 4 15 15')
frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

inputted_value = StringVar()
user_help = StringVar()
total_guesses_left = StringVar()
secret_word_value = StringVar()
invalid_input = StringVar()

empty = " "
invalid_guess = "Invalid Guess. Please Enter a letter from A-Z"


word_entry= ttk.Entry(frame, width=7)
word_entry.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))

exit_button= ttk.Button(frame, text='Exit', command=exity)
exit_button.grid(column=1, row =7, sticky=(W))

entered_guess = ttk.Label(frame, text='Enter a Letter')
entered_guess.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=(W, E))

secret_guess = ttk.Label(frame, textvariable=secret_word_value)
secret_guess.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E, N, S))

guesses_label= ttk.Label(frame, text='Guesses Remaining:')
guesses_label.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=(W, E))

total_guesses = ttk.Label(frame, relief ="sunken", textvariable= total_guesses_left)
total_guesses.grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=(W, E))

user_details = ttk.Label(frame, textvariable = user_help)
user_details.grid(column=1, row = 5, sticky=(W, E))

invalid_guesses = ttk.Label(frame, textvariable = invalid_input)
invalid_guesses.grid(column=1, row = 6, sticky =(W, E))

secret_word = ttk.Label(frame, text='Secret Word:')
secret_word.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

enter_button = ttk.Button(frame, text='Enter', command = initalize_loop)
enter_button.grid(column=3, row =2, sticky=(W, E))



for child in frame.winfo_children():
    child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

enter_button.focus()
enter_button.bind('<Return>', initalize_loop)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if_true = True
    while if_true == True:
        wordList =[]
        loadWordList("Words.txt")
        word = random.choice(wordList)
        guessed_letter = []
        total_guesses = 10

        secret_word_value.set(getHint(word, guessed_letter))
        total_guesses_left.set(guessed_letter)
        invalid_input.set(empty)
        user_help.set(empty)

        root.mainloop()
        if_true = messagebox.askyesno(icon="question", title= "Play Again?", message ="Would you like to play again?")
    exit(0)
```

Comment: What is the value of `total_guesses_left.get()` at this moment?

Comment: the base value should be set to 10 but while its > then 0  it shud run that loop.
The idea of the program is a GuessingGame with a Gui

Comment: That's very nice. But what is the actual value whe the error occurs? Debug your code! Maybe add a `print` call before the line causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you initialize the variable here:

```
total_guesses_left = StringVar()
```

Then, inside `if __name__ == "__main__":` you write:

```
    guessed_letter = []
    // ...
    total_guesses_left.set(guessed_letter)
```

So our `StringVar` instance stored as `total_guesses_left` gets its value set to an empty list. As it's a `StringVar`, this leads to a conversion, which means that its internal value now is the string "`[]`".

Then in your `initalize_loop`, you try to do

```
    total_guesses = int(total_guesses_left.get())
```

Of course `total_guesses_left.get()` will return a string, or more precisely it will return the string "`[]`".

And as `int` parses strings representing numbers with a specific base (by default 10), it can only handle strings consisting of alphanumeric characters, and only if they only contain characters used by the specified number base (i.e. by default those are only the characters `0123456789`).

Therefore you get the exception that "`[]`" can not be parsed as `int`.

You probably want `total_guesses_left` to store a valid integer representation string and not one of a list.

Answer (score -1):

It means at that moment your `total_guesses_left.get()` is giving '[]'. base 10 error arises when you try to convert a char or something other than a number which is as a string like

```
    >>> str1='a'
    >>> int(str1)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
    >>> alist='[]'
    >>> int(alist)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[]'
```

I hope you understand the error. Play around a little with errors. "Trial And Error " :D

Comment: figured out what my problem was, the code there was fine it was down further when i was referencing it i used the wrong reference

Comment: nice. happy coding :)